# Unity _MainTex property doesnt exsit when it clearly does

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders

So Im trying to create an outline using shaders and materials, however, i cannot seem to get the image of the material reflecting the image on the sprite render, please help.

Like it keeps saying i dont have _MainTex but its quite clear i do, and ive tried everything, even setting it programmatically.

[image: Image of the issue]

edit - i was using shader graph, im new to shader graph, and the tourtial i follow said it was name must match.

I found out after much heart break it was the reference.

Comment: The property name inside the shader must match "_MainTex" exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You need set Reference is _MainTex
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3Xc.png)

Answer (score 2):

What you show is only the display name for the Inspector .. the property name might differ from that! (See [Writing Shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadersOverview.html)) Important is the first name here:

```
Properties {
    // | this matters
    // |       | this is only for the Inspector!
    // V       V 
    _MainTex ("My Texture", 2D) = "white" { }
}
```